# Keyword match(Exact Match) in Elasticsearch ignoring the order of keywords

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am working on a use case where in I need only exact match but the words can be in any order. 
Example :-

```
        Searching with Text :- Quick Brown Fox 
        Should Match with :- 
          - Quick Brown Fox (Can Achieve with analyzer Keyword)
          - Brown Quick Fox
          - Fox Quick Brown
        Shouldn't Match with :-
          - Brown Quick Fox Rocky
          - My Brown Quick Fox Rocky
```

If i try to use match with slop 0, the issue is I am also getting matches with **Brown quick Fox Rocky** which is not desirable. So i am looking for a analyzer which can be used with keyword but can handle the order of word. Till now no success achieved any ideas from the community is most welcome.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very ideal, but I think it gets the job done.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": { 
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "whitespace",
        "fields": {
          "length": { 
            "type":     "token_count",
            "analyzer": "whitespace"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Key elements here:

- `whitespace` analyzer (because this is what I see in your test data; if you have some other rules, you need to change this)
- `token_count` type of sub-field that, at indexing time, indexes the number of tokens from that specific field

Then, at search time, the idea is for your text to search to match all the terms and, also, **to have the length of tokens equal to the one indexed**. Not ideal, I said, because the number of token in the searched text needs to be computed before running the query and placed inside the query. If a simple analyzer is used - like the `whitespace` one - you can achieve this outside Elasticsearch with a simple tokenizer of some sort (depending on the application/language you are using) and compute the number of tokens.

And the query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "text": {
                            "query":"Quick Brown Fox",
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "text.length": 3
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, the `3` you see there needs to be computed outside Elasticsearch by "looking" at the searched text.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I am able to achieve the desired response but as you said and I still feel its not ideal. Need to find some different logic or work at the backend to handle this. Will accept the answer though. Thanks again.